# cURL and Bash, capture variable and value from string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Using bash, grep, split, awk, or sed, I would like to capture

```
ASPSESSIONIDSUSTQBQS=AAHNFMBAGABAILMKCDGIIMFJ
```

from

```
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSUSTQBQS=AAHNFMBAGABAILMKCDGIIMFJ; secure; path=/
```

*'ASPSESSIONID'* remains always the same + 8 random characters (*SUSTQBQS*).

Also this variable may not always be located in the second columns or right after *'Set-Cookie: '*

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please show what you tried, we're not here to do your coding for you. The parameter expansion operators in `bash` should be of use, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: All right, I'll post it but I'm pretty sure it's non sense as I don't get the structure of split, and cut refuse a delimiter of more than one character

Comment: Have you tried using the `bash` pattern matching functions in the link I gave you?

Comment: If you are using gnu grep, you can use `-o` option to return specific portion of the string only, i.e. `grep -o "ASPSESSION[^;]*"`

Comment: Your question is incompletely specified.  Once you specify the problem, the solution will be obvious.  Are you trying to capture the text starting with "ASPSESSIONID" and terminating before the next semi-colon? Or are you looking for the string that ends with IMFJ?  Or are you looking for a certain number of characters?  Perhaps you just want everything until 2 characters  before the string "secure".  Clarify the problem and the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic regex structure is the same in various programs.
It may be explained in words as: The text between the colon/space(: ) and the semicolon (;). Which, in regex parlance is:

```
: ([^;]*);
```

And could be assigned to a var:

```
RE=': ([^;]*);'
```

Then, we could use it in

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
while read l; do
      [[ $l =~ $RE ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
done <file
```

[gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
gawk -v RE="$RE" '$0 ~ RE { print gensub(".*"RE".*","\\1",1); }' file
```

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -rn 's/^.*'"$RE"'.*$/\1/p' file  # using -r avoids the several `\`
```

Comment: Thank you for the regex explanation and practical examples. I was likely using the wrong tool for this task.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F"[ ;]" '{print $2}' FileName
```

Set the field seperator as `space` and `;`. Then print the `2nd field`.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: chovy: U can accept this as the answer then... :-)

Comment: I didn't ask the original question.

Comment: didn't notice that :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sed` command

```
sed 's/[^:]\+..\([^;]\+\).*/\1/' FileName
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^:]\+      -- Remove the charecters until :
..          -- Remove two characters
\([^;]\+\)  -- Capture the group until ; found 
.*          -- Remove the all character after capture the group

\1          -- Finally print the captured group
```

**Output :**

```
ASPSESSIONIDSUSTQBQS=AAHNFMBAGABAILMKCDGIIMFJ
```